# A word that means the ability to detach oneself from past work

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

A valuable trait in business (as well as in life) appears to be the ability to detach oneself from past work.  The **inability** to do so could be called *authorship bias* and is related both to [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) and to the [sunk cost fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_costs#Loss_aversion_and_the_sunk_cost_fallacy).

Is there a word in English to describe this skill ?

Comment: You could say that they were **unhindered** by previous work, although this suggests that they might not have done any at all.

Comment: You may be looking for the term *(maintaining) objectivity*.

Comment: Please add an example sentence how you would use that word.

Answer (score 1):

What about an idiom, if you can't find a single word,  ...

**To draw a line under something**,

> it is finished and you do not think about it again

See answer at https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34432/131620

So you could say she is able to draw a line under _____, and move on and refocus...

Answer (score 0):

flexible, from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flexible)

> Able to change to cope with variable circumstances: "a flexible and
>   quietly competent administrator"

When circumstances change, the flexible person adopts a different approach that may be very different from his/her earlier approaches or methods.  However, if someone is too "flexible", she may betray her principles for expediency's sake.

Answer (score 0):

To **see with fresh eyes** is used to describe this skill. Attributed to Marcel Proust:

> Le véritable voyage de découverte ne consiste pas à chercher de nouveaux paysages, mais à avoir de nouveaux yeux.

Google translates the above sentence as:

> "The real voyage of discovery consists not in seeking new landscapes but in having new eyes. "